# How can I use a file.js in a component vue

Tags: javascript, html, file, import, vue-component

I tried to use prueba.js in one of the components of my app (InputSwap.vue), in which there is a button ('console.log'). I want to use this file using that button, but the app showed me this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97w8G.png)

prueba.js let me see the data in the console by clicking the button.
The data was saved with window.localStorage:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('data_input', JSON.stringify(data));
```

where am I wrong?

---

prueba.js :

```
export default {
   infoPrueba() {
        var data = (JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('data_input')))
        console.log(data)
    }
}
```

InputSwap.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="card-action">
      <Button v-on:click="prueba()"
        v-bind:style="{'margin-left' : '5px', background : '#52368c'}"
        btext="Console.log" icon="code"
      />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Button from './Button'
import * as prueba from './prueba.js' // I have prueba.js in components folder
export default {
  name: 'InputSwap',
  components: {Button},
  methods: {
    prueba: async function () {
      prueba.infoPrueba()
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: import {infoPrueba} from './prueba.js'  you can use destructuring

Comment: I tried import {infoPrueba} from './prueba.js' and const { infoPrueba } = require('./prueba.js') and both didn't work. I think the problem is inside prueba.js

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  x-rw, I solved this problem:

I changed import * as prueba from './prueba.js'  to import {infoPueba} from './prueba.js'

and I wrote this code in prueba.js:

```
export const infoPrueba = () => {
  var data = (JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('data_input')))
  console.log(data)
}
```